# Magento Worldpay Extension Config Instructions? - Phoenix

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, extensions

Does anyone have the Phoenix Magento Worldpay configuration instructions? This extension seems to have been removed from Magento Connect but is still up on GitHub.

I can't find the configuration instructions anywhere! Phoning up Worldpay didn't help much, they weren't able to help me get it working. It almost works, but not quite.

I found instructions on the old Magento Forum, but they didn't work.

Any help configuring this would be very gratefully received!

Comment: Can you add the instruction you found that doesn't work for you

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/236952/
Thanks, the payment response url is the problem, I think.

Comment: The url should be `site.com/worldpay/processing/response` Take a look at https://github.com/PHOENIX-MEDIA/Magento-WorldPay ... confix.xml and app/code/community/Phoenix/Worldpay/controllers/ProcessingController.php

Comment: I get a callback failure when I use that url.

Comment: I've tried with the index.php added. Worldpay support told me to use `<WPDISPLAY ITEM="MC_callback">` but when I use that I get an error occurred message and it takes me to an empty checkout.
If I use `http://<WPDISPLAY ITEM="MC_callback">` there's no  callback but the order still says Payment Pending.
I can't find the confix.xml? And the ProcessingController.php means nothing to me as I don't know php.
Thanks for any help here.

Comment: Not sure.. take a look at http://docs.woothemes.com/document/worldpay/ ... http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/no-redirect-and-order-status-pending-payment-41507.html ... http://support.worldpay.com/support/kb/bg/paymentresponse/pr5502.html

Comment: Thanks for those, this is helpful. Copying the folders could work but unfortunately I don't really understand the folder structure of Magento yet so have no idea where to put them.

Comment: You can NOT just copy folders in magento they need to be in a specific path

Comment: Exactly! I'm not risking it!

Comment: I'm getting a 302 error. File has moved. Has anyone resolved this before?

Comment: Are you running the latest version?

Comment: Yes, latest version of magento and the last version of the phoenix worldpay that was available on magento connect. I've asked webhosts to look for any 302 redirects on the server causing errors.

Comment: Apparently no 302 redirects. No idea on this one.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for your help @R.S ! It seems to have been a simple typing error. I went and filled in all the information in Magento and Worldpay again and it now works. If anyone else gets this issue I used <WPDISPLAY ITEM="MC_callback"> in the payment response url. And triple check your typing.

Comment: Add your comment as an answer or close the question, so we can keep the site clean

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have been a simple typing error. I went and filled in all the information in Magento and Worldpay again and it now works. If anyone else gets this issue I used  in the payment response url. And triple check your typing.